Hypothetical scenario where the seed doesn't rot after sprouting the plant
Suppose a seed was sprouted in such a way that after it sprouted, it did not rot and was connected to the plant.
If so, will the connected seed keep releasing enzymes needed for the glyoxylate cycle?

This phenomenon is fairly common in plants, it is called vivipary.

@bob1 Thank you for the input. I am not sure vivipary fits my exact situation, but it seems interesting. If the seed develops while still attached to the mother plant (as seen in vivipary), would it release glyoxylate cycle enzymes back to the mother plant?
